# How do you have a URL in homepage of Edge Chromium?

Tags: microsoft-edge, sharepoint-online

We set a homepage through GPO's on all PC's in the domain. When you open a new tab our SharePoint online intranet opens.
As it's a new tab, the URL field is empty, ready to go to the site you want.
But if people navigate through our intranet (SharePoint online), the URL field stays empty.
That is confusing.

Is there a way to make a click in the intranet page fill up the URL field? Could something be done with a redirect page?

Answer (score 0):

This relates more to the way you have designed the page.

It seems like you are using
[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))
with JavaScript to modify the new tab page, rather than using true URL
to point to new pages.

You should modify the new tab page to use URLs, instead of
in-place modifications, if you wish the address field
to contain a URL.

Comment: Hi Harry, this is just a policy as shown in edge://policy/ and it referes to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/  nothing fancy or special. Links go to another URL.

Comment: A real URL should be displayed in the address field.

Comment: Hi Harry, if you use a policy to set an URL it won't show. You'll notice this when creating a new page in MSEdge. (the default page is a MS search page with a background image), it won't have an URL. That is the question I'm asking.

Comment: A click should display its address. New-tab itself doesn't have an address. So you stay with an empty field until the user click a real URL (not one that points inside the same page). There is no way to change that, unless you set up a dummy new-tab page that immediately redirects to a URL.

Comment: I think we're talking next to eachother. I've used default microsoft functionality (GPO) and it works as I've described. I agree with you that seems weird, hence my question.

Comment: Yes, I'm wearing here the hat of a web designer, and my subject is the design of your new tab page, not at all the GPO which only defines this page. The solution I'm talking about is a re-design of the page that will avoid this problem. If you're looking for a way to force Edge to display the URL, then I don't know of a solution.